# Milnor-Bloch-Kato conjecture implies the Beilinson-Lichtenbaum conjecture

Tags: motivic-cohomology, ag.algebraic-geometry

Voevodsky reformulated the Milnor-Bloch-Kato conjecture as a change-of-topology morphism from the Zariski to the étale topology of a *field* with torsion coefficients being an isomorphism.  The Beilinson-Lichtenbaum conjecture is more generally about such an isomorphism for *varieties* and integer coefficients. How does the former imply the latter (sketch/reference)?

Comment: The Beilinson-Lichtenbaum conjecture is about torsion coefficients.:)
You could have a look at http://www.math.uiuc.edu/K-theory/handbook/1-351-428.pdf

Comment: Also note: when you consider a morphism of topologies, it suffices to verify an isomorphisms of complexes of sheaves at (the corresponding) points. If you have rigidity (or purity), Nisnevich points reduce to fields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To go from finite coefficients to integral coefficients, one notes that
rationally, Zariski and etale cohomology agree (this boils down to the fact that higher
Galois cohomology is torsion), and compares the two long exact sequences associated to the short exact sequence of coefficients $\mathbb Z(n) \to \mathbb Q(n) \to \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z(n)$.
One can go up to degree $n+1$ because of (the analog of Hilbert's theorem 90) 
that the degree $n+1$ etale cohomology vanishes.

To go from fields to smooth varieties over a field, one compares the local-to-global
spectral sequences
$$ \bigoplus_{x\in X^{(s)}} H^{t-s}(k(x),\mathbb Z/m(n-s)) \Rightarrow H^{s+t}(X,\mathbb Z/m(n))$$
for both theories, 
where $x$ runs through the points $x$ of codimension $s$ with residue field $k(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

From the Handbook of K-Theory (mentioned by Mikhail Bondarko in the above comments):

p. 202, Thomas Geisser:

"In [91], Suslin and Voevodsky show that, assuming resolution of singularities,
the Bloch–Kato conjecture (1.10) implies the Beilinson–Lichtenbaum conjecture
(1.11) with mod m-coefficients; in [34] the hypothesis on resolution of
singularities is removed."

[91] A. Suslin, V. Voevodsky, Bloch–Kato conjecture and motivic cohomology
with finite coefficients. The arithmetic and geometry of algebraic cycles
(Banff, AB, 1998), NATO Sci. Ser. C Math. Phys. Sci., 548 (2000), 117–189.

[34] T. Geisser, M. Levine, The Bloch–Kato conjecture and a theorem of Suslin–
Voevodsky. J. Reine Angew. Math. 530 (2001), 55–103.